# How do I solve an issue on a PHP page returning error 500 on IIS when there's no logging trace available?

Tags: php, iis

I'm working on IIS 10, php 7.4.32 (but i tried 8.0/8.2/8.3).
I have many websites with php and works fine.

I don't know how to debug or fix a problem with a specific website, a php page that return me ERROR 500, PHP and IIS doesn't log anything.

Can you help me?
This is the index:

```
include( 'config/config.inc.php' );
if  ( empty( $_GET ) ) {
    $_GET = NULL;
}
$server = new RestServer();
try {
$server->handle();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $log->LogError('index.php --> '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

**config.inc.php**

````
<?php
spl_autoload_register( function( $class ) {
    require_once( 'classes/' . $class . '.php' );
});
?>
<?php
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'utf-8' );
session_start();
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
mb_http_output( 'UTF-8' );
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Rome' );
?>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

?>
<?php
$log = new KLogger ( 'logs/error.txt' , KLogger::DEBUG );
?>
<?php
$GLOBALS['method'] = $_GET['url'];
define( 'DODEBUG', false );
?>
<?php
if ( DODEBUG ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST ) ) {
        $log->LogInfo( var_export( $_REQUEST, true ) );
    }
}
?>
<?php
$GLOBALS['Url'] = 'https://xxx';
$GLOBALS['clientid'] = 'xxx';
$GLOBALS['secret'] = 'xxxx';
$GLOBALS['Path'] = 'https://xxxx';
?>```
````

Comment: You should start by properly configuring error reporting and logging via your PHP configuration. Anything you try to do from _within_ any scripts, with ini_set and error_reporting, might already be too late, depending on where the error actuallyoccurs.

Comment: It's just a 500 error. You can also narrow down the scope of the problem based on its sub-status codes. Simply refer to these documents: [HTTP Error 500.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-error-500-when-you-visit-web-site) and [500 - Internal server error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code#500---internal-server-error)

Comment: I have php logs but, it works but there are only PHP Notice. I haven't any Warning or Fatal Error.

This is the error:

Module       FastCgiModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
                php-7.4.32
Error Code  0x8007000d

Comment: 0x8007000d says:
ISAPIModule module is missing

But all others PHP pages works..

Comment: PHP pages? or other websites? Please make sure to add the corresponding module for the site where you are currently experiencing problems. Refer to this part of the document for specific steps: [HResult code 0x8007000d](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-error-500-when-you-visit-web-site#hresult-code-0x8007000d)

Comment: PHP pages.
This problem is only on index.php, i have other.php, about.php etc and works. index.php give me that error

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know PHP very well. Maybe you can try redeploying the application or comparing index.php to other pages to narrow down the problem. Have you correctly [Configure IIS to Handle PHP Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis#configure-iis-to-handle-php-requests-by-using-iis-manager)?

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't set the error logging on your server at all, maybe this is a great idea to use try {your_code_here} catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } ?

Comment: Nothing happened, same error. 
I have php logs but, it works but there are only PHP Notice. I haven't any Warning or Fatal Error. 
This is the error: Module FastCgiModule Notification ExecuteRequestHandler php-7.4.32 Error Code 0x8007000d